# How do I copy the first letter of a last name in a another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using Excel, in one cell is the name Smith, James.  How do I copy the first letter of the last name, S, in another cell?

Comment: I have to say, this question shows little research. I googled "excel first letter of last name" and the very first hit (from StackOverflow, as it turns out) shows how to use the `LEFT` function to extract the first character in a cell.

Comment: Hi, Susan. Welcome to Super User. We are here to help you, not do it for you. So, if you could share with us what you have already attempted and where you ran into a problem, we would be happy to help. Otherwise, this question may be closed at some point for the reasons @EngineerToast pointed out. Additional help is available by reading [ask].

Answer (score 2):

With **Smith, James** in cell **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,1)
```